# Plotting multivariate function under one constraint

Tags: python-3.x

I have three variables with a constraint, say `relation(x, y, z, *args)` = 0, where 'relation' is a highly non-linear function of x, y, and z. All x, y, and z that satisfy the relation are my solutions, which will be plotted on a 3D axes (I know how to do that given the data points).

So, how should I go about solving this? The easy way is to pass a large `numpy.meshgrid` of 3 dimensions, say of size `(1000, 1000, 1000)` and then constraint the values so that `z = numpy.nan` if `numpy.abs(relation(x, y, z)) >= epsilon` where `epsilon` defines the accuracy that I need. However, I will need to then compress this 3D meshgrid to a 2D meshgrid with corresponding values of `z` supplied, something I don't know how to do. Also, I think this is going to be extremely slow, and unoptimized.

Any advice on how I can either compress the 3D meshgrid to a 2D meshgrid formed of only `z` values at different `x, y`, or on any other way to solve this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.